# Check the linearity of a function which is the difference of two squared expressions

Tags: functions

Consider the following function
$$
\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i+1\right)^2-\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\right)^2
$$
**Question:** Is this function always linear in $a_1,..., a_n$?

For example, if $n=1$,
we have
$$
a_1^2+1+2a_1-a_1^2=1+2a_1
$$

If $n=2$,
we have
$$
(a_1+a_2+1)^2-(a_1+a_2)^2=1+2a_1+2a_2
$$

Does this extend to any $n$?

Comment: Yes, ______________

Comment: Thanks. Is it true that my function is $1+2\sum_{i=1}^n a_i$?

Comment: Yes, it is true. Just use the multinomial expansion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i+1\right)^2-\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\right)^2
& =\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\right)^2+2\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\right)+1 - \left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\right)^2 \\
& =2\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\right)+1 \\ 
& =2a_1+2\left(\sum_{i=2}^n a_i\right)+1\\
\end{align}

Comment: Could also be done by using $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$